# Find check out status of SharePoint 2013 wiki page

Tags: 2013, wiki, check-out, status

How do I find the check out status of a SharePoint 2013 wiki page?

Alternatively, how do I find out any documents that are actually check out to me or "Exclusive" or locked to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this

1. Open the Pages library settings and then choose "Manage files which have no checked in version". This will give you the information
2. You can create a new view and choose field "Checked Out To". Then group by that field.

Comment: someone thoughtfully disabled "library settings" so 1 is out for me....

Comment: Second option works.... I can't even upvote your answer yet, but thanks a lot.  It is correct.  Also, thanks for providing two options ...